# Is this integral being calculated correct?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, partial-fractions

[image]

I've got this integral on top and I have to find it using the cauchy's integral formula and I tried this approach to solve it.

I know how to apply the formula but I just need help solving this part because it's been a long time since I last used the partial fractions method.

Regarding the |z|= 4, just forget it, I am going to use it somewhere else.

I think I am doing something wrong and I know that I shouldn't stop here, but I want to make sure that what I'm doing is correct.

Comment: Use of Residue Theorem will cut your hard work and make calculation easy.

Comment: You have not indicated the contour you are integrating (nor the direction). Also, if you want to work this by partial fractions, you should break it into linear factors of the denominator, not quadratic. As Math-Learner says, the Residue theorem is much simpler. Or if you dont have it yet, you can use Cauchy's theorem to convert your integration to a sum of integrations around each pole separately (which is how you prove the residue theorem). This would still be easier than partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final answer that I found.

[image]